# Javascript dataTables populating data issue (no errors returned)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using data tables and trying to popular a table with data.

The data I have looks like this:

```
<table id="mytable" class="display" width="100%"></table>

{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "6700",
      "user": {
        "firstName": "somename"
      },
      "Count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

So this is what I've done:

```
var dataSet = {
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "6700",
            "user": {
                "firstName": "somename"
            },
            "Count": 0
        }
    ]
};

jQuery('#mytable').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { "users": "id" }
    ]
});
```

I'm am not getting any errors but the data is not inserted either.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data` option you need to provide variable that contains array of objects (`dataSet.users`). Also in `columns.data` option you need to define property within each object in the array (`id`).

Corrected code is shown below.

```
jQuery('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "data": dataSet.users,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id", "title": "ID" }
    ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/f99hjahm/) for demonstration.